# Não consigo ir para outra página com a função header

Tags: php

Estou tendo problema com o `header()`, fiz uma programação de alterar os dados do banco de dados e quando clica no botão para poder alterar ele vai para uma página em branco então coloquei o `header("Location: AdmAgenda.php");` para que pudesse voltar para a página já com os dados atualizado mas está dando erro:

> A página de localhost não está funcionando
>
> Redirecionamento em excesso por localhost Tente limpar os cookies.

O que posso fazer para corrigir?

meu código:

```
<?php 
$idSeg = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-segunda");
$seg = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "seg");

$idTerca = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-ter");
$tercaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "ter");


$idQuarta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-quarta");
$quartaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qua");


$idQuinta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-quinta");
$quintaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "qui");

$idSexta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-sexta");
$sextaa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "sex");

$idSabado = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id-sabado");
$sabadoo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "sab");


include("conexao.php");


if($link) {
    $segg = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_segunda set horas_de_segunda='$seg' where id='$idSeg';");
    $terc = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_terca set horas_de_terca='$tercaa' where id='$idTerca';");
    $quarr = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_quarta set horas_de_quarta='$quartaa' where id='$idQuarta';");
    $quinn = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_quinta set horas_de_quinta='$quintaa' where id='$idQuinta';");
    $sexx = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_sexta set horas_de_sexta='$sextaa' where id='$idSexta';");
    $sabaa = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE horas_sabado set horas_de_sabado='$sabadoo' where id='$idSabado';");
    header("Location: AdmAgenda.php");
}
else{
    die("Erro: " .mysqli_error($link));
}
?>
```

Comment: O redirecionamento é pra mesma página? Loop infinito?

Comment: isso... teria que voltar para a pagina

Comment: Coloque um `if` para prevenir que entre na condição que faz as alterações e o redirect.

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Não concordo com a forma como você está fazendo as coisas, pois só redirecionar não vai dar a informação de "Atualização realizada com sucesso" para o usuário,  mas se você mudar:

```
if($link) {
```

para:

```
if($link && isset($_GET["seg"])) {
```

já resolve o problema da forma que vc quer.

Answer (score 0):

Em que pese não ser a melhor prática, não há problema em redirecionar para a mesma página, desde que você saiba o que está fazendo e consiga escrever sua lógica de uma forma que nunca caia em um redirecionamento infinito (o navegador na verdade cancela o loop quando verifica que há muitos redirecionamentos para a mesma página, lançando algo como `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`). Assim, não chega a travar a navegação.

No seu problema específico, você está apenas verificando se a variável `$link` (que pelo contexto, depreende-se que é uma conexão aberta com o `mysql`) não é `null`, ou seja: **sempre** (se tudo estiver certo).

Para evitar isto, ao invés de verificar se há conexão, verifique se a url está enviando os parâmetros para salvar. Sugiro colocar acima do seu `if($link) {` algo assim:

```
if ( $idSeg && $seg && $idTerca && $tercaa && $idQuarta && $quartaa &&
     $idQuinta && $quintaa && $idSexta && $sextaa && $idSabado && $sabadoo ) {

    if($link) {
        /* funções de update */
        header("Location: AdmAgenda.php");
    } else{
        die("Erro: " .mysqli_error($link));
    }

}
```

Isso implicaria em só atualizar o banco e redirecionar se todos estes parâmetros estiverem presentes (não sei se esta é a lógica da sua aplicação, mas é apenas para fins de explicação, você adapta). Uma abordagem mais *clean* é verificar um a um. Feito isto, quando você redirecionar, os parâmetros não irão ser enviados e, consequentemente, não cairão neste `if`.

Comment: Então, quando eu fiz a programação cru cada vez que eu alterava o dados e clicava no botão ele iria para uma outra página em branco, ai pensei se fosse para cair em uma página em branco que caia na página adm.php novamente pois assim já atualiza a página automáticamente

Comment: E colega tentei dessa forma continuar indo para pagina em branco o que seria?

Comment: Bom dia @Nathan, o erro de excesso de redirect foi corrigido? o script `AdmAgenda.php` é o que renderiza o formulário, correto? quando ele não cai no 'header` para redirecionar, ele continua o script normalmente, e vai executar tudo que está nele, depois desse `if`.

Comment: Não consegui, nem mesmo com esse codigo amigo, o script que faz alteração do banco e outro, esse `AdmAgenda.php` ele seria o corpo de onde vizualizo e coloco os dados para poder alterar, ao clica no botao de alterar deveria dar um redirect na pagina para poder ver novamente (como se fosse um f5).